# How to use useStyle to style Class Component in Material Ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, react-component

I want to use useStyle to style the Class Component . But this can be easily  done hooks. but i want to use Component instead. But I cant figure out how to do this.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';


    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      '@global': {
        body: {
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
        },
      },
      paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      }
}));

class SignIn extends Component{
  const classes = useStyle(); // how to assign UseStyle
  render(){
     return(
    <div className={classes.paper}>
    <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
      <LockOutlinedIcon />
    </Avatar>
    </div>
  }
}
export default SignIn;
```

Comment: You missed the brackets, it should be 
const classes = useStyle();

Answer (score 91):

You can do it like this:

```js
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
});

class ClassComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    searchNodes: ""
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>Hello!</div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(ClassComponent);
```

Just ignore the `withTheme: true` if you aren't using a theme.

---

To get this working in TypeScript, a few changes are needed:

```js
import { createStyles, withStyles, WithStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => createStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
});

interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles>{ }

class ClassComponent extends Component<Props> {

// the rest of the code stays the same
```

Comment: Offical example from Material UI using Higher-order component API: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api

Comment: Thanks. *As I tried, we don't need `{ withTheme: true }` even when we have a theme!*

Comment: The hero we need but don't deserve ! We have moved away from class based components, they are a mess compared to React.FC but for the modal to work with Material-UI we had to go with Class based component. This worked perfectly with Typescript.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems incompatible with refs in TypeScript. Previously I could make a ref to the component with `useRef<MyComponent>(null)`, but his no longer works because `MyComponent` is no longer a type. More troubling, TypeScript reports that "Property 'ref' does not exist" on the component returned from `withStyles()()`, but an ugly hack involving `any` makes the error go away, and the code seems to work.

Answer (score 25):

for class Components you can use `withStyles` instead of `makeStyles`

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = theme => ({
fab: {
  position: 'fixed',
  bottom: theme.spacing(2),
  right: theme.spacing(2),
},
  });

class ClassComponent extends Component {
   render() {
            const { classes } = this.props;

            {/** your UI components... */}
      }
} 


export default withStyles(useStyles)(ClassComponent)
```

Comment: I'ver had the same problem and followed your suggerstion, but props comes empty without the style. Any tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Hey I had a similar problem. I solved it by replacing `makeStyles` with `withStyles` and then at the point where do something like `const classes = useStyle();`, replace that with `const classes = useStyle;`

You notice `useStyle` is not supposed to be a function call but rather a variable assignment.

That should work fine after you've made those changes.

Answer (score 6):

`useStyles` is a react hook. You can use it in function component only.

This line creates the hook:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({ /* ... */ });
```

You are using it inside the function component to create classes object:

```
const classes = useStyles();
```

Then in jsx you use classes:

```
<div className={classes.paper}>
```

Suggested resources:
https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: For a class component, you can use `withStyles`.

Comment: In the documentation linked to in this answer, it is under the "higher-order component API" heading.

Answer (score 3):

Like other answers already stated you should use [`withStyles`](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component) to augment a component and pass the `classes` through the properties. I've taken the liberty to modify the [Material-UI stress test example](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#stress-test) into a variant that uses a class component.

Note that the `withTheme: true` option is normally not needed when you simply want to use the styles. It is needed in this example because the actual value of the theme is used in the render. Setting this option makes `theme` available through the class properties. The `classes` prop should always be provided, even if this option is not set.

```js
const useStyles = MaterialUI.withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: (props) => ({
    backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor,
    color: theme.color,
  }),
}), {withTheme: true});

const Component = useStyles(class extends React.Component {
  rendered = 0;

  render() {
    const {classes, theme, backgroundColor} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        rendered {++this.rendered} times
        <br />
        color: {theme.color}
        <br />
        backgroundColor: {backgroundColor}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

function StressTest() {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState('#8824bb');
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = React.useState('#eae2ad');

  const theme = React.useMemo(() => ({ color }), [color]);
  const valueTo = setter => event => setter(event.target.value);

  return (
    <MaterialUI.ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        <fieldset>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="color">theme color: </label>
            <input
              id="color"
              type="color"
              onChange={valueTo(setColor)}
              value={color}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="background-color">background-color property: </label>
            <input
              id="background-color"
              type="color"
              onChange={valueTo(setBackgroundColor)}
              value={backgroundColor}
            />
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <Component backgroundColor={backgroundColor} />
      </div>
    </MaterialUI.ThemeProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<StressTest />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do this, albeit a bit of a workaround.

Some may say this doesn't really answer the question, but I would argue that it does. The end result is `useStyles()` delivers the styling for a class-based yet multi-part parent component.

In my case I needed a standard Javascript class export so that I could call `new MyClass()` without a `MyClass is not a constructor` error.

```js
import { Component } from "./react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  someClassName: {
    ...
  }
}));

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <RenderComponent {...this.props} />;
  }
}

function RenderComponent(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    /* JSX here */
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how to add multiple classes in ClassName with class component

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },
  label: {
    backGroundColor:"blue"
 }
});

class ClassComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    searchNodes: ""
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;//   
    return (
      <div className={classes.root + classes.label}>Hello!</div> //i want to add label style also with
    );
  }
}
```