# Importing useStyles into a function - TypeError: prevDeps is undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been using class components and importing my useStyles files with const classes = useStyles();. What is the correct way to use this in a function?

The classes.formControl etc is being used on each of my MaterialUI dropdowns and they are throwing the errors. Does I need to write this as a hook? do I need to remove makeStyles from my styleSheet?

error message

```
TypeError: prevDeps is undefined
areHookInputsEqual
```

```
const classes = useStyles();

        return (

            <form>

<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
   <InputLabel id="Enter-the-dive-type">Dive Type</InputLabel>
      <Select
       labelId="Enter-the-dive-type"
       id="Enter-the-dive-typer"
       value={dive.typeID}
       onChange={handleChange}>
       <MenuItem value="">
       <em>None</em>
       </MenuItem>
       <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
       <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
       <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

styles

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

    table: {
        maxWidth: 450,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
    formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 120,
    },
    selectEmpty: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}));
```

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox for this?

Comment: @Jimbo Gee see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554586/how-to-use-usestyle-to-style-class-component-in-material-ui